# how to create a SOAP UI project and run requests to it in Java

Tags: java, soapui

I want to create a Java class that will do the following
1. load/create a SOAPUI project using a wsdl.
2. run requests to the operations in that wsdl.

This is my SoapJavaTest.java file(though this is not complete, it is just registering a project in SOAP UI and printing the operations contained in it)

```
public class SoapJavaTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String projectFile ="SoapUIJavaTest\\SoapUIProjects\\soapui-project1.xml";
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject (projectFile);
        //WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://metalmaker.net/metalmaker.asmx?WSDL");
        WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
        for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()){
            WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
            System.out.println("OP:"+op.getName());System.out.println(op.createRequest(true));
            System.out.println("Response:");System.out.println(op.createResponse(true));
            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting the following error - 'NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaTypeSystem;'.

I have included the following jar files
1. commons-cli-1.2
2. commons-httpclient-3.1
3. log4j
4. soapui-3.6-beta2
5. soapui-xmlbeans-2.0.2
6. wsdl-xmlbeans-1.1
7. xbean-1.0.3
8. xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.2.0
9. XmlSchema-1.0.3

What jar file am I missing or is it the wrong classes that I am using? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did this work for you finally? maven as suggested might get the correct dependancies

Comment: I didnt try Maven. I integrated SoapUI and Junit by following [this link](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html). However in that we are setting an already saved Soap UI project in the Junit test. I wanted to do something like creating and then saving the SOAPUI project at some desired location provided that I only have to use service wsdl. Any idea how to implement that through code.

Comment: The problem was with the jar files included in the project classpath.We need to include all the jar files available in the soapUI-4.5.1\lib folder in our project classpath.However,I am getting another problem.I have tried the following code `String projectFile ="SOAPUITests/SoapUIProjects/soapui-project1.xml";
SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject (projectFile);` but I am getting  `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: SOAPUITests/SoapUIProjects/soapui-project1.xml` error in `WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject (projectFile)` line.

Comment: attempting to reproduce in 2017 using maven. Smartbear now owns soapui so all of the classes and package names are difference and your sample code no longer works. Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve this. I am creating a SoapUI project, saving it and sending requests all via code. Please refer to [link](http://pritikaur23.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/saving-a-soapui-project-and-sending-requests-using-soapui-api/) here for complete details. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than programmatically calling SoapUI to run your tests, have you considered using the `maven-soapui-pro-plugin` ?

Here's an introduction to [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html), if you need to read about it :)

Now, given you have a maven project, edit your `pom.xml` and add a profile similar to the one below. Then you can run maven with -Dsoapuitests, and your SoapUI test suite(s) will run.

```
    <profile>
        <id>soapuitests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-soapui-pro-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>soapuitests</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <endpoint>http://myserver/myendpoint</endpoint>
                                <projectFile>
                                    ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/my-soapui-project.xml
                                </projectFile>
                                <projectProperties>
                                </projectProperties>
                                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}\soapui-logs</outputFolder>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I hope this is of help to you, good luck.

Comment: what if i want to do it programmatically? how to accomplish it using java?