# How to create request from WADL programatically in java

Tags: java, rest, wsdl

Is there any way we can create request from WSDL for REST services in java?.programatically Read/parse  WSDL and append the values to query paramets and execure request.I was able to find example for WSDL as in here

```
package com.bbog.soap;

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Operation;

    public class WsdlAnalyzer {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
            WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://localhost:7000/Solicitud?wsdl");
            WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
            for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
                WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
                System.out.println("OP:"+op.getName());
                System.out.println(op.createRequest(true));
                System.out.println("Response:");
                System.out.println(op.createResponse(true));
            }
        }
    }
```

The link are:
 [how to generate a SOAP message with a fully populated request from WSDL without code gen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487699/how-to-generate-a-soap-message-with-a-fully-populated-request-from-wsdl-without)

[how to create a SOAP UI project and run requests to it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773173/how-to-create-a-soap-ui-project-and-run-requests-to-it-in-java)

Is there something similar in REST to read WADL?. Any help is appreciated.Thanks.